# What is the issue with this sample code in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am learning angularJS. I have tried a calculator using angularJS. Two combo boxes having inputs and the other combo box is having the operations. When the user clicks the button then it has to show the results based on the operation which the user selected. But i could not able to find why it is not showing any output. Could you please help me

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('calculate', [])
    .controller('CalculateController', function() {
      this.input1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
      this.input2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
      this.selectedInput1 = 0;
      this.selectedInput2 = 0;
      this.selectedOpr = '=';
      this.operations = ['*', '/', '+', '-'];
      this.calculate = function calculateValues(value1, value2, opr) {
        alert('coming inside calculate function..');
        if (opr == '+') {
          return (value1 + value2);
        } else if (opr == '-') {
          return (value1 - value2);
        } else if (opr == '*') {
          return (value1 * value2);
        } else if (opr == '/') {
          return (value1 / value2);
        }

      };
      this.output = function show() {
        alert('Calling function..');
        alert('Output is :' + this.calculateValues(this.selectedInput1, this.selectedInput2, this.selectedOpr));
      };
    });
})(window.angular);


 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-2-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="invoice1.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
  <div ng-app="calculate" ng-controller="CalculateController as calc">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
   Input 1:
    <select ng-model="calc.selectedInput1">
      <option ng-repeat="c in calc.input1">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Input 2:
    <select ng-model="calc.selectedInput2">
      <option ng-repeat="d in calc.input2">{{d}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Operation:
    <select ng-model="calc.selectedOpr">
      <option ng-repeat="e in calc.operations">{{e}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="calc.show()">Pay</button>
    <br>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Manivannan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `output` method which is available in your controller context.

To avoid context issue while using `this` inside `function` create `var vm = this;` in your controller and replace `this` with `vm` throughout the controller.

**Markup**

```
<button class="btn" type=="button" ng-click="calc.output()">Pay</button>
```

Here you output function should look like need to change `this.calculateValues` to `this.calculate`

**Code**

```
  this.output = function show() {
    alert('Calling function..');
    alert('Output is :' + vm.calculate(vm.selectedInput1, vm.selectedInput2, vm.selectedOpr));
  };
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/licSGVd88hIuGdjYos4B?p=preview)

**Update**

You could use `ng-options` to avoid type conversion while doing arithematic operation, as here what will happen in when you use `ng-repeat` for rendering `options` those value would get converted to `string`, then you again need to cast them to `number` by `parseInt`, so `ng-options` will be better here to use.

```
<select ng-model="calc.selectedInput1" ng-options="c for c in calc.input1"></select>
<select ng-model="calc.selectedInput2" ng-options="c for c in calc.input2"></select>
<select ng-model="calc.selectedOpr" ng-options="c for c in calc.operations"></select>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jilJW4X2xGN2O0T2Fi3?p=preview)

Comment: Also dont forget to parseInt the value1 and value2 of calculate method because the `+` operator will only concatenate the two values

Comment: Yes you correct..but that problem wont come if we use ng-options here

Comment: @ThisIsMarkSantiago check updated answer..I've added this part

Comment: I've up-voted your answer for including/covering that part

Comment: @Mani Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no method name `show`

try to call `output` instead

Like this

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="calc.output()">Pay</button>
```

**N:B**:

in output

change this

```
this.calculateValues
```

to

```
this.calculate
```

as there is no method named `calculateValues`

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVjoXN)

Comment: @Anand thanks mate for the link codepend . i have to add some additional code.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked. But i need to understand we should add '+' in the variable (ex +value1 + +value2) in the function.

Comment: if there is + attached with variable , it'll treated as number instead of string @Mani

Comment: Thank you so much @Anik .. Now i understand